# AudioTrack stream is choppy

Tags: android, audio, android-asynctask, audiotrack

I'm trying to send audio via a Server to my android phone where I play it (streaming).
The server sends audio bytes every 50 milliseconds.

This solution works but it isn't proper (to receive and writing in the audiotrack in the same loop (writing take some times))

```
private class SoundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        [...]

            AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 16000,4, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, BUF_SIZE,    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            [...]
            byte[] output;              
            at.play();
            byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];

            //Here is the loop
            while(true)
            {                                    
                DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, BUF_SIZE);                    
                socket.receive(pack);
                at.write(pack.getData(), 0, pack.getLength());      
            }
        }           
    }
```

So I tried to separate the receiving and the writing in two threads but it doesn't work, the sound is choppy after a few seconds !
My two threads (using a ArrayBlockingQueue)
Producer :

```
public void run() {     
        [...]
        byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];  
        while(true)
        {                            
            DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, bufferSize);              
            socket.receive(pack);               
            queueAudio.put(pack);                       
        }
    }
```

Consumer :

```
    public void run() {
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,  16000, 4,   AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize,     AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    audioTrack.play();
    while(true)
    {
        DatagramPacket packet;
        try 
        {
            packet = queueAudio.take();                         
            audioTrack.write(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getData().length); 
        }
```

I noticed when the size of my queue is equal to 1 the sound is normal, and when it is superior to 1 (after a 2-3 seconds) the sound is choppy.

Can somebody explain to me why my audiotrack isn't working ??
Thanks in advance !

EDIT :

Okay, I understood the problem. The problem come from the receveing of UDP Packets, normally I Shoud receive my packets every 50 milliseconds.

I calculate the time interval between receiving two packets, it appears that sometimes this is interval is superior to 100 milliseconds and just after that it is less than 1 millisecond !!!

When this happen the sound become choppy. I resolved this problem simply : when the interval is inferior to 1 millisecond, I don't put the data in my queue.

This works, the sound isn't choppy but there is somme little cut sometimes.

How can I solve this ? Is there a way to receive my UDP packets regularly ? Should I try to do the receiving in a Service ???

Comment: How much are you processing in that 50ms? perhaps you're consuming too little? Also what are the quality aspects?

Comment: No I don't think so, the buffer size for 50 ms is 1600 bytes.
The encoding format is PCM 16 bits and the sample rate is 16000 Hz.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a larger buffer size for the AudioTrack than the size of the chunks that you write to it. From the documentation for the [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#AudioTrack(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) class:

> **bufferSizeInBytes** the total size (in bytes) of the internal buffer where audio data is read from for playback. If track's creation mode is MODE_STREAM, you can write data into this buffer in chunks less than or equal to this size, and ***it is typical to use chunks of 1/2 of the total size to permit double-buffering***.

Create the AudioTrack with a larger buffer:

```
AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                16000, 4, 
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                BUF_SIZE * 2, // use a buffer twice the size of
                              // the chunks you will write to it
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

But keep writing chunks of the same size. Hopefully the double-buffering will eliminate the choppiness. If that doesn't work you can also try increasing `BUF_SIZE`.

Comment: I try your solution to use a larger buffer but this doesn't work, the sound is still choppy.
Also increasing BUF_SIZE dont' change anything.
I've often have 3 seconds long "normal" sound and after it goes choppy.

But thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I understood the problem.
The problem come from the receveing of UDP Packets, normally I Shoud receive my packets **every 50 milliseconds.**

I calculate the time interval between receiving two packets, it appears that sometimes this is interval is superior to 100 milliseconds and just after that it is **less than 1 millisecond** !!!

When this happen the sound become choppy.
I resolved this problem simply : when the interval is inferior to 1 millisecond, I don't put the data in my queue.

This works, the sound isn't choppy but there is somme little cut sometimes.

How can I solve this ? Is there a way to receive my UDP packets regularly ?
Should I try to do the receiving in a Service ???

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure AudioTrack is not waiting for audio to be consumed while there is nothing more to play in its buffer, thus try without streaming from network the PCM data to verify the bottleneck is not coming from your stream. Profile your code to identify where the bottleneck comes from.

Second, don't write to AudioTrack inside `onProgressUpdate` because this is done inside the UI thread and writing to AudioTrack is blocking. You will need to create, start and feed your AudioTrack object inside another separated thread.

Finally, I don't recommend using AsyncTask if you plan to play audio for more than few seconds, quoting the documentation: `AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)`

Comment: There is no problem with the stream, but with my audiotrack.

I try to make 2 threads one with receiving the packets and another with the Audiotrack. 

It's a typical producer/consumer using a ArrayBlocking queue (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).
But the sound is still choppy.
My first implementation with receiving and writing the packet in audiotrack in the DoInBackGround works but this not the way I should Do.

Comment: EDIT : I notice, in my log, when the size of my BlockingQueue is equal to 1, the sound is normal  but when the size is superior to 1 the sound is choppy